# Bot protection or addition of CAPTCHA to sign up experience in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, bots, azure-ad-b2c, captcha

I am using Azure AD B2C as the authentication solution for a Dynamics CRM Portal application. So far, B2C allows customization of the sign-up experience, which i have done to customize the look and feel of the signup/signin page but I don't see any option to incorporate a CAPTCHA.

Is there any way of detecting and blocking robots during AD B2C Sign Up process ?

Other than reCAPTCHA, is there any other bot protection mechanism that can be used on the B2C Sign Up page ?

Answer (score 2):

The email verification that, by default, is required during the sign-up process is meant to prevent bots from creating fake users.

Comment: Thank you Chris Padgett. Yup we have that indeed. My concern was is that enough to block bots from signing up and creating accounts via B2C ?

Answer (score 0):

As Javascript is not yet available using CAPTCHA would not be possible. Also the standard fallback for these services "iFrames" would also be stripped by the B2C UI. However it does use the standard AAD account lockout password policy 
"After 10 unsuccessful sign-in attempts with the wrong password, the user is locked out for one minute. Further incorrect sign-in attempts lock out the user for increasing durations of time"

Comment: Thank you Phil Whipps. Yes, i tried to enable CAPTCHA for default Portal signUp page (whilst B2C swicthed off) However, on switching on B2C - CAPTCHA doesn't appear - just as you said. B2C does not support CAPTCHA.

Comment: Also, account lockout after 10 unsuccesful login attempts is great - but that comes into play after registering and having an account. Am looking for some kind of bot-protection that does not let bots register and create fake accounts at all during SignUp process !